# Links in c# textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, hyperlink

I have a custom Jabber IM client and I'm having a problem with links.  When something like http://something.com is entered I want it to show up as a link in the message window.  The message window is a standard c# textbox.  Is there a way to mark it as a link so that it can be clicked and open the webpage?

Thanks

Comment: This will get you started.. [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/RichTextBoxLinks.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/RichTextBoxLinks.aspx "Rich Text Box Links") Good luck!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A RichTextBox can detect URL's, I don't think a regular TextBox can detect them. However you can always use a Single line RichTextBox for your input.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f591a55w.aspx

Comment: Over 4 years later, and your answer is still helping people! Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could be of some help :)

Answer (score 6):

The solution provided by Mr Jamie Garcia is a great one, referenced by the supplied MSDN article link.  However, given that this solution was proposed so long ago, I would like to propose an updated one.

The [MSDN solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f591a55w.aspx) launches Internet Explorer and passes the URL to the program directly.  I feel a better (and more user-centered) approach would be to launch the link within the user's **default web browser**.

We still set up an event handler for the `LinkClicked` event of our `RichTextBox` control, but with a few changes.  Here is the complete code:

```
// Event raised from RichTextBox when user clicks on a link:
private void richTextBox_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    LaunchWeblink(e.LinkText);
}

// Performs the actual browser launch to follow link:
private void LaunchWeblink(string url)
{
    if (IsHttpURL(url)) Process.Start(url);
}

// Simple check to make sure link is valid,
// can be modified to check for other protocols:
private bool IsHttpURL(string url)
{
    return
        ((!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url)) &&
        (url.ToLower().StartsWith("http")));
}
```

As the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f591a55w.aspx) states, the `DetectUrls` property of the `RichTextBox` control is enabled by default, so any valid http/https urls will automatically appear as underlined hyperlinks.

Comment: _"DetectUrls property of the RichTextBox control is enabled by default, so any valid http/https urls will automatically appear as underlined hyperlinks."_   LinkClicked events will only happen on underlined hyperlinks (validated by the Control), so why do we need to validate?

Comment: Re comment: 'why to we need to validate?'
A RichTextBox also treats non-http links as valid links. e.g. file://
Although the op does not request as such, the validation is limiting to just http(s) links, rather than all links