# Create hyperlink in TextBox control

Tags: c#, winforms, hyperlink, textbox

Is there some way that I could create a hyperlink within a Textbox control? The catch: I would like only *certain text* to act as a hyperlink. For example, StackOverflow.com allows me to make only [THIS](http://#) text act as a hyperlink. Is there some way to do this in C# from withing a Textbox?

Comment: Try look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/321037/735864 or here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/330850/735864 I think also you can use something like this: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php

Comment: richTextbox - I'll give it a go. I didn't realize that RTB had such capabilities until just now.

Comment: Try to follow this msdn page regarding the inclusion of a link within of a RichTextBox control. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f591a55w.aspx Bye

Comment: richTextBox -> nothing but a road to The Major Pain. If you are up to using markup text boxes, for the love of all sacred, don't use richtextbox.  Editing text in it is impossible without API of some kind...

Answer (score 1):

Use a RichEditCtrl. Does the text need to be editable? Otherwise you could use Labels and Hyperlinks in a StackPanel.

Comment: Is your answer related to winforms or WPF? Can't find _"hyperlinks in stackpanel"_ in Winforms..

Comment: This was written for WPF.