# Is it possible to make a word clickable in a textbox that can do something on click?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, textbox

I have a textbox in my project that the user enters a simple type of scripting syntax for my application. I am trying to figure out if it is possible to make a certain word in the textbox clickable so when my user clicks it it will bring up a openfiledialog and then replace the word with the file chosens path.

My first though would be to search the textbox and get the xy coordinates of the word and then change the cursor when it is over that word and when the textbox was clicked it would bring it up. Although I don't think that will work because the x/y value will change and it would not help me to replace the right word.

This word can show up many times in a textbox...If it is possible with a standard textbox then any guidance on how I can implement this would be appreciated.

Comment: Winforms or WPF application?

Answer (score 0):

Without writing up an entire class for you, I would probably start perhaps with [GetCharIndexFromPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getcharindexfromposition.aspx).  With this you can specify the top-left and bottom-right corners of the textbox to find the index of the first and last visible characters in the textbox.

From there you would just have to parse out the keyword of interest between those bounds (should be fast because you only have to search through visible chars).  I would then specify a set of `Rect`s, this time using [GetPositionFromCharIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getpositionfromcharindex.aspx) which bound the keywords.  You could use GDI to draw them, even, for debugging.  You could probably do all of this in `OnPaint` or some other appropriate handler (whenever output of the textbox changes).

In the `MouseMove` handler, then, you would just have to check the mouse position against the bounding `Rect`s to identify being in the active region (setting the cursor icon, etc), and being aware of that state in `OnClick` to do whatever you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

[Refer to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855292/links-inside-rich-textbox)

You could easily create a javascript link that when clicked would trigger a function or a postback with a command argument if you wish to interact with a codebehind.