# How can I handle or remove the trailing space of a LinkLabel?

Tags: c#, winforms, linklabel

I'm trying to insert links into my `RichTextBox`. I do not mean setting DetectUrls to true, I want alternate text. What I have so far seems to be working mostly fine.. I'm using much of the code from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26783475/2957232). But my issue is that there is some trailing whitespace in the `LinkLabel` that end up cutting off some of the text that follows it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //My text with a placeholder for the link: %link1%
    //NOTE: I can see the leading '>' fine, but the '<' gets hidden by the link label, and it looks like a space between the link text and "Near..."
    richTextBox1.Text = "This has a link here:>%link1%<Near the middle.";

    LinkLabel link1 = new LinkLabel();
    //link1.Margin = new Padding(0); //Doesn't help
    //link1.Padding = new Padding(0); //Default is already 0
    //What I want to see in my hyperlink
    link1.Text = "My_Link_Text";
    link1.Font = richTextBox1.Font;
    link1.LinkColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
    link1.LinkClicked += Link_LinkClicked;
    LinkLabel.Link data = new LinkLabel.Link();
    //For now, just test with google.com...
    data.LinkData = @"http://google.com";
    link1.Links.Add(data);
    link1.AutoSize = true;
    link1.Location = this.richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("%link1%"));
    richTextBox1.Controls.Add(link1);
    //Replace the placeholder with the text I want to see so that the link gets placed over this text
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace("%link1%", link1.Text);

    //Attempt to manually shrink the link by a few pixels (doesn't work)
    //NOTE: Turns out this cuts back on the link test, but leave the trailing space :(
    //Size s = new Size(link1.Width, link1.Height); //Remember the autosized size (it did the "hard" work)
    //link1.AutoSize = false; //Turn off autosize
    //link1.Width = s.Width - 5;
    //link1.Height = s.Height;
}
```

The LinkClicked event, just for the curious. Nothing special.

```
private void Link_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Link.LinkData.ToString());
}
```

Here is what I see, for reference (notice the missing '<'):

[image]

The reason for using a `RichTextBox` is that I also plan on adding formatting when I am finished (ability for text to be bold, colored, etc.). I'm basically 2 hours away from scrapping the `RichTextBox` and drawing everything manually onto a panel and handling click position...

Comment: Can you explain why you are avoiding the DetectUrls?  Embedding a link label inside a RichTextBox seems like an odd way to do this.

Comment: @LarsTech - It's not that I'm avoiding DetectUrls, but I don't necessarily want to show a user the actual link in favor of text. For example, similar to SO, where if I want to click on your username, the link says "LarsTech" and not "https://stackoverflow.com/users/719186/larstech"